# WiFi working sporadically on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for the first time a couple of weeks ago on my HP Probook 4540s. Everything worked perfect until yesterday, when WiFi connectivity suddenly became very disrupted.

Here's the problem: I can connect to the WiFi, but the Internet works only for about 10-15 minutes, after which it no longer works. The Internet works again after I disconnect and reconnect my WiFi. I'm sure it's not a problem pertaining to my WiFi router since the same network works on every other device, except for my laptop.

Please note that I'm new to Ubuntu, and am still in the process of figuring out the basics. I looked at other forums with similar problems,but couldn't find a solution.

I tried the following commands into the Terminal, but to no avail.

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo rmmod -f rt2800pci
sudo modprobe rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here's some more info in case you need it...

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/390368d4268eb26bfa5c015602580343.png]

[image: https://gyazo.com/f247fd6db73b1fff6a5a3857874708b8]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you install 14.04, unless you have a specific reason to stay with 12.04.  This problem may be caused by a wireless driver, which is often fixed with newer versions of the Linux kernel.

I've heard of issues with this laptop's graphics not playing nicely with Ubuntu, but I could not find any information on wifi problems.  Are you experiencing any other issues?  It may be a problem on the hardware side of things.

Here's what you should do: install 14.04 LTS unless you really need to stay with 12.04.  If that doesn't help, make sure nothing is wrong with the hardware itself.  Finally, if your laptop is in great condition, but the problem persists, run the program "additional drivers" It will search for available drivers for your hardware, and may fix the problem.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, my bad. I have 14.04 LTS. I ran additional drivers, but to no avail. No additional drivers were found.